# Leaflet open a popup on marker click from GeoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have made a **leaflet** map.
Data is loaded using **GeoJSON**
on the **onEachFeature** event I have bound the popup with a **dynamic content** text taken from some property of the feature.

The problem is that with the code I've written **the popup is shown only on the first click**, then I click again on the same marker it doesn't show up.

here is the code:

```
function showMarkets() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/API/GetMarketsWithStatus',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
    }).done(function (geoData) {
        mapLayers.markets = L.geoJSON(geoData, {
            onEachFeature: onEachMarketFeature
        }).addTo(map);
    });
}
function onEachMarketFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
        layer.bindPopup('<a href="http://some-url-to-call?mktid=' + feature.properties.code + '">' + feature.properties.name + '</a>');
        this.openPopup();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind your popup when the feature is created, not when the user clicks on it, Leaflet will handle the click events for you:

```
function onEachMarketFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<a href="http://some-url-to-call?mktid=' + feature.properties.code + '">' + feature.properties.name + '</a>');
}
```